# Rails query with join returns less results than should

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

Why my query returns only 34 records, but there is more than 300 records to return?

Query 1:

```
2.1.5 :109 > Refinery::BeerBrands::BeerBrand.all.count
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refinery_beer_brands`
=> 34
```

Query 2:

```
2.1.5 :106 > Refinery::BeerBrands::BeerBrand.joins(:brewery).count
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refinery_beer_brands` brewery
=> 34
```

Query 3:

```
2.1.5 :112 > ::Refinery::Breweries::Brewery.all.count
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refinery_breweries`
=> 303
```

Query 4:

```
2.1.5 :111 > ::Refinery::Breweries::Brewery.joins(:beer_brands).count
(1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refinery_breweries` INNER JOIN `refinery_beer_brands` ON `refinery_beer_brands`.`brewery_id` = `refinery_breweries`.`id`
=> 34
```

Query 5:

```
2.1.5 :126 > ::Refinery::Breweries::Brewery.joins(:beer_brands).where(:refinery_beer_brands => { beer_type: [0,1,2,3,4,5] } ).count
(1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refinery_breweries` INNER JOIN `refinery_beer_brands` ON `refinery_beer_brands`.`brewery_id` = `refinery_breweries`.`id` WHERE `refinery_beer_brands`.`beer_type` IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
=> 34
```

Why the "query 5" returns only 34 records? All "beer_brands" must have "beer_type" selected, and it is in db number 0-5. I want to return 303 records. Each brewery has many beer_brands.

Brewery model:

```
  has_many :beer_brands, :class_name => '::Refinery::BeerBrands::BeerBrand'
```

Beer brand model:

```
  belongs_to :brewery,:class_name => '::Refinery::Breweries::Brewery'
```

How to get all 304 records with similar query? I want to filter records with different array in query.

**//edit 16.3.2015:**

Ok, you're right... But I have another problem. What about this case:
1) brewery can have beer brands, but it doesn't have to
2) I want fulltext search in brewery title or their related beer brands titles

Now my query looks like:

```
  out.includes(:beer_brands).where("refinery_breweries.title LIKE ? OR refinery_beer_brands.title LIKE ?", "%#{pars[:query]}%", "%#{pars[:query]}%")"
```

Now it throws error:

```
  Unknown column 'refinery_beer_brands' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would think adding an additional `where` clause would suddenly yield *more* records. If you get 34 results in the first query, adding a `where` can never give you *more* than the original unrestricted 34 results. `where` clauses are *restrictive*. They filter out 0 or more of the records that would otherwise be selected. If I say "show me all red cars", and I get 10 results, and then I say "show me all red cars with four doors", there aren't going to be *more* cars that fit this new additional criteria.

Comment: Of course... I wanted to show what I mean in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query 1 and 2 shows that you have only 34 records in beer brands which means that only few breweries have beer brands and not all 303 and this is why it is returning only 34 records. If you still need all the 303 records use `left outer join` or `right outer join`. But you will obviously get null values for the other breweries.